# php - How to count array values and keys until a target is reached

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of values and I need to count them but only until I reach the $target amount. I need to know how many array keys are required to reach the target ($count) and the sum total of those corresponding values ($total). Here's the array I'm using:

```
$numbers = Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 6 [5] => 1 [6] => 5.5 [7] => 1 [8] => 1 [9] => 1 [10] => 1 [11] => 1 [12] => 1 [13] => 11 )
```

With the `$target=9` the `$total` should be 10 and the $count should be 5 but I'm getting `$total=9` and `$count=9` as the code appears to be counting the keys rather than values. Similarly if the target were 12 then `$total` should be 16.5 and the `$count` should be 7 but i get 12 and 12.

Hope it all makes sense. If someone can edit this code so that it works for any array of numbers and any target it would be greatly appreciated.

```
$count=0;
$target=9;
$total=0;
foreach($numbers as $key => $value){
while($total < $target) {
$total = $total+$value;
$count++;
}
}
echo "total is $total and count is $count";
```

Comment: What is `$outgoing`?  Why do you have a `while` inside your `foreach`?

Comment: probably you want to use `$target` instead of `$outgoing`

Comment: edited error to say $target rather than $outgoing

Answer (score 3):

```
$target = 9;
$total = 0;

foreach($numbers as $key => $value) {
    if ($total >= $target) {
        break;
    }

    $total += $value;
}

echo "total is $total and count is $key";
```

Comment: Might want to add some explanation, or some text of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Rename $outgoing to $target, and change while to if

```
$count=0;
$target=9;
$total=0;
foreach($numbers as $key => $value){
    if($total < $target) {
        $total = $total+$value;
        $count++;
    }
    else
    {  
        break;
    }
}
echo "total is $total and count is $count";
```

UPD: Rewrote code to avoid unused loop entries with break

Comment: Also want to mention that in this case the solution will be array key independant as long as array values are numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can put a check you `$key` if key is equal and greater than to `$target` break foreach loop. Something like this -

```
<?php

$numbers = Array ( 0 => 1, 1 => 1, 2 => 1, 3 => 1, 4 => 6, 5 => 1, 6 => 5.5, 7 => 1, 8 => 1, 9 => 1, 10 => 1, 11 => 1, 12 => 1, 13 => 11 );

$count=0;
$target=9;
$total=0;

foreach($numbers as $key => $value) {
  if ($key >= $target) {
    break;
  }
  $total += $value;
  $count++;
}

echo "total is $total and count is $count";
?>
```

Hope this result in what you actually wanted. (y).

Answer (score -1):

Add an if statement

```
$total = 0;
foreach($numbers as $key => $value)
{
    $total = $total+$value;
    if($total >= $target)
    {
       $count = $key+1;
       break;
    }
}
```

And you don't need `while` loop.

Comment: You need to increase the `$total` somewhere or it will stay at 0.

Comment: yea, that was example of just if statement but thats point, I'll add this to code